# Problemas com conversor JSF: "f:convertNumber"

Tags: jsf-2.2, conversão-de-tipo

Boa noite a todos,

Em uma aplicação que desenvolvi em JSF o conversor  funcionou bem rodando localmente com banco mysql local (JPA/Hibernate)

mas quando fiz o Deploy da aplicação e coloquei em produção (servidor) não funcionou como deveria. As versões do Tomcat são as mesmas.

saída na máquina local:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

saída no servidor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam que além de não mostrar o "R$" da moeda os valores estão desconfigurados!

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: já tentou usar os atributos extras da tag como <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="R$" locale="pt_BR" /> ?

Comment: olá wryel tudo bem? Obrigado por responder minha perguntar, esqueci de postar a tag:<f:convertNumber currencyCode="BRL" type="currency"/> amanhã testarei esses atributos extras só não entendo o porquê de não ter dado erro ao executar localmente. Só dar este erro no servidor.

Comment: Bom Dia, O problema do símbolo do real foi resolvido com currencySymbol="R$" agora tenho que resolver o problema das casas decimais ao cadastrar: 248,89 é salvo: 24,889.00. No form de cadastro o inputText tem uma máscara para valores monetários e também um <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00" />

Comment: Eu não tenho ambiente agora para testar, mas com certeza é algum atributo que pode estar faltando, eu já fiz isso no passado. Como você mencionou, tente trocar seu pattern para #.##0,00 (se atente a posição da virgula que você informou).